# get priority items from a list and insert them into the same list at given position c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of 50 sorted items(say) in which few items are priority ones (assume they have flag set to 1).

By default, i have to show the latest items (based on date) first, but the priority items should appear after some 'x' number of records. Like below

index 0: Item
index 1: Item
index 2: Priority Item  *(insert priority items from this position)*
index 3: Priority Item
index 4: Priority Item
index 5: Item
index 6: Item

The index 'x' at which priority items should be inserted is pre-defined.

To achieve this, i am using following code

**These are my 50 sorted items**

```
var list= getMyTop50SortedItems();
```

**fetching all priority items and storing it in another list**

```
var priorityItems = list.Where(x => x.flag == 1).ToList();
```

**filtering out the priority items from main list**

```
list.RemoveAll(x => z.flag == 1);
```

**inserting priority items in the main list at given position**

```
list.InsertRange(1, priorityRecords);
```

This process is doing the job correctly and giving me the expected result. But am not sure whether it is the correct way to do it or is there any better way (considering the performance)?
Please provide your suggestions.

Also, how is the performance effected as i am doing many operations (filter, remove, insert) considering the increase in number of records from 50 to 100000(any number).

Update: How can i use **IQueryable** to decrease the number of operations on list.

Comment: 100000 is still not much. Have you measured it and got some idea what sort of performance you need? Id bet on the time taken for input and output to be far greater than the actual sort.

You could do it with a single list/array by sorting them in that order. If the top 50 is already sorted and you can't change that, you can do it all in-place but the difference would be really small.

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation on `InsertRange`:

> This method is an O(n * m) operation, where n is the number of
>   elements to be added and m is Count.

n*m isn't too very good, so I would use LINQ's `Concat` method to create a whole new list from three smaller lists, instead of modifying an existing one.

```
var allItems = getMyTop50();
var topPriorityItems = list.Where(x => x.flag == 1).ToList();
var topNonPriorityItems = list.Where(x => x.flag != 1).ToList();

var result = topNonPriorityItems
    .Take(constant)
    .Concat(topPriorityItems)
    .Concat(topNonPriorityItems.Skip(constant));
```

I am not sure how fast the `Concat`, `Skip` and `Take` methods for `List<T>` are, though, but I'd bet they are not slower than O(n).

Comment: You should measure it, there are plenty of cases where `O(n)` or `O(1)` can be slower than other solutions where `n` is not really big.

Comment: Yeah, especially on solutions using a `HashSet<T>`. I don't think the constant time should be that high on `List<T>`s, though.

Comment: Its a fair few extra objects, `Concat` and `Take` is creating iterators and stuff as well

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem you're actually trying to solve is just sorting the list of items. If this is the case, you don't need to be concerned with removing the priority items and reinserting them at the correct index, you just need to figure out your sort ordering function. Something like this ought to work:

```
// Set "x" to be whatever you want based on your requirements --
// this is the number of items that will precede the "priority" items in the
// sorted list
var x = 3;

var sortedList = list
   .Select((item, index) => Tuple.Create(item, index))
   .OrderBy(item => {
       // If the original position of the item is below whatever you've 
       // defined "x" to be, then keep the original position
       if (item.Item2 < x) {
          return item.Item2;
       } 

       // Otherwise, ensure that "priority" items appear first
       return item.Item1.flag == 1 ? x + item.Item2 : list.Count + x + item.Item2;
}).Select(item => item.Item1);
```

You may need to tweak this slightly based on what you're trying to do, but it seems much simpler than removing/inserting from multiple lists.

**Edit**: Forgot that `.OrderBy` doesn't provide an overload that provides the original index of the item; updated answer to wrap the items in a Tuple that contains the original index. Not as clean as the original answer, but it should still work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i compared the execution time with original code(mentioned in question) and i noticed that original code is taking less time to execute. Even though the difference is in milli-seconds this code is taking 2x time..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a single enumeration of the original collection using linq-to-objects. IMO this also reads pretty clearly based on the original requirements you defined.

First, define the "buckets" that we'll be sorting into: I like using an enum here for clarity, but you could also just use an int.

```
enum SortBucket
{
  RecentItems = 0,
  PriorityItems = 1,
  Rest = 2,
}
```

Then we'll define the logic for which "bucket" a particular item will be sorted into:

```
private static SortBucket GetBucket(Item item, int position, int recentItemCount)
{
  if (position <= recentItemCount)
  {
    return SortBucket.RecentItems;
  }
  return item.IsPriority ? SortBucket.PriorityItems : SortBucket.Rest;
}
```

And then a fairly straightforward linq-to-objects statement to sort first into the buckets we defined, and then by the original position. Written as an extension method:

```
static IEnumerable<Item> PrioritySort(this IEnumerable<Item> items, int recentItemCount)
{
  return items
    .Select((item, originalPosition) => new { item, originalPosition }) 
    .OrderBy(o => GetBucket(o.item, o.originalPosition, recentItemCount))
    .ThenBy(o => o.originalPosition)
    .Select(o => o.item);
}
```